# Insert New Table row with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to add a new Table row with an input type file, after each time someone chooses a file to upload.

The problem is, the input type is not inserted into the new row;

The markup language:

```
<table id = "images">
    <tr>    
        <td>Title: </td><td><input type="text" name="title" size="51" required><td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Description:  </td><td><textarea type="text" name="story" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea><td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Author:  </td><td><input type="text" name="auth" size="51" required></textarea><td>
    <tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Image:  </td><td><input type="file" name="image[]" size="20" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" required onChange="addRow('images')"></input><td>
    <tr>
</table>
```

The JS:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">          
    addRow(tableID) 
    {       
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-2);

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = "Images";

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "file";
        element2.name = "image[]";

        document.getElementsByName("image[]").lastChild.setAttribute("onChange", "addRow('images')");

        cell3.appendChild(

    }
</SCRIPT>
```

The error I'm seeing is:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAttribute' of undefined

Any help greatly appreciated.

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function addRow(tableID) 
    {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
        var row = table.insertRow();

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = "Image:";

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input");
        element2.type = "file";
        element2.name = "image[]";

        cell3.appendChild(element2);
        element2.setAttribute("onChange", "addRow('images')");
    }
```

here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/C3GRN/1/

Answer (score 2):

JAVASCRIPT

```
document.getElementById('images').innerHTML+="<tr><td>blah-2</td></tr>";
```

JQUERY

```
$('#images tr:last').after('<tr><td>blah-2</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('#images tr:first').after('<tr><td><input type="text" ></td></tr>');
```